# Is there a String#indexOf equivalent that counts code points (not code units)?

Tags: javascript

Is there a `String#indexOf` equivalent that counts code points (not code units), or do you have to enumerate the string yourself using `String.prototype[@@iterator]` (eg using `for...of`)?

```js
console.log('d'.indexOf('')) // 3!
```

Comment: `Array.from("d").indexOf("")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
console.log([...'d'].indexOf(''))
```